# Delete SQL statement in VB.NET

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net

I am new to VB.NET and as well as MySqL. I want to delete records in my database. 
Using,

```
    Dim SQLStatement As String = "DELETE name,date FROM people"
    RetrieveInfos(SQLStatement)
```

Where,

```
Public Sub RetrieveInfos(ByRef SQLStatement As String)
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

    With cmd
        .CommandText = SQLStatement
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = SQLConnection
        .ExecuteNonQuery()

    End With

    SQLConnection.Close()
    SQLConnection.Dispose()
End Sub
```

But there is an error of InvalidOperationException, I am confused. 
I want to delete records in my database without referencing the " WHERE number = VALUE " in order to delete the previous recorded value. Is that possible?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you need an update statement instead of delete statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few problems:

1. You do not specify column names in the delete statement since you are deleting records.
2. Your command, should it be successfully executed, will delete every record in the people table.
3. You are closing and disposing the SQLConnection at the end of the RetrieveInfos method. If this connection is open elsewhere in your code, only the first execution of the code will work.
4. Your method should not be called Retrieve if it is deleting.
5. The command should be wrapped in a using statement

   ```
   Using cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
       With cmd
           .CommandText = SQLStatement
           .CommandType = CommandType.Text
           .Connection = SQLConnection
           .ExecuteNonQuery()
       End With
   End Using
   ```

Comment: In addition: you are trying to drop the columns off of the table, are you not? This is not the right syntax to change the database schema. If you are trying to remove the actual values in the columns, this is also wrong. You need to UPDATE command for that.